# double function only returning -0

Tags: c++, function

I have two functions as part of a larger function I'm writing as an exercise. The purposes of the functions are to convert temperatures from Fahrenheit to Celsius and vice versa.

I start with:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
double Celsius_to_Fahrenheit(double);
double Fahrenheit_to_Celsius(double);
```

The Celsius-to-Fahrenheit works fine:

```
double Celsius_to_Fahrenheit(double C){
    double F = ((9 / 5)*C + 32);
    return F;
}
```

But the Fahrenheit-to-Celsius function returns `-0` no matter what argument it takes:

```
double Fahrenheit_to_Celsius(double F){
    double C = ((5 / 9)*(F - 32));
    return C;
}
```

What's wrong with the second? I can't see any difference in structure that would cause one to work and not the other.

edit: I only tested the functions on `0`, both functions break for non trivial arguments! That's even worse!

Comment: Welcome to the world of integer division. Try `double C = ((5.0 / 9.0) * (F - 32.0));`.

Comment: The Celsius-to-Fahrenheit function doesn't work either.

Comment: @user2357112 I tested it on zero only! Silly me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually I believe BOTH functions fail. You just don't notice that C-to-F fails because you get a nonzero result back.

In C++ the result type of division depends on the type of the operands, NOT the type that would most accurately represent the result. In other words, 5/9 is *integer division*, and will be truncated down to 0. If you use something like 5.0/9.0 it will do the math as double precision and most likely give you a result that you're desiring.

If however you're content with a truncated result you can just rearrange the terms to make it do the rounding as late a possible: `double C = ((F - 32) * 5 / 9);`